# How to load in 10 million sha256 hashes - NodeJS memory problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, redis

I have a web application that uses sha256 hashes to generate the outcome of a game.
How can I store these hashes and access them.

I've tried loading them and storing them into an array, but the data is too large and Node throws an overflow error. I also looked into redis, but the memory cap on a key-value pair is also too small to store 10M hashes.

What would be the ideal approach to store these hashes?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory size of your NodeJS process? Depending on your program, you may quickly reach the default limit processing 10M items.  See this article for details on increasing your NodeJS process memory size https://medium.com/@vuongtran/how-to-solve-process-out-of-memory-in-node-js-5f0de8f8464c.

Comment: I have not. I'll take a look thankyou.
I had considered perhaps writing all these hashes to a database and then read them sequentially using an incremental primary key or something like that.

Comment: Take a look https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/index.html

Comment: Redis should have no problem managing 10M sha256 values. Stored in binary should be less than 1 GB of memory, stored in hex text should be a bit more than 1 GB. Your Redis node needs to have this much memory available, check `maxmemory` setting.